# Log all debug messages to file | JBoss 7

Tags: logging, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, jboss-logging

I'd like to log every single debug messages into some file by adding some logger in standalone.xml.

The app is runnning on jboss 7 . How can I do so ?

P.S. : I already have a root logger to output INFO level things to console.I tried to add a second one but it seems that it's not allowed.

```
<root-logger>
      <level name="INFO"/>
      <handlers>
          <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
      </handlers>
</root-logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want debug messages to end up on the console you just need to change the level to `DEBUG`. With CLI you'd execute;

```
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:write-attribute(name=level, value=DEBUG)
/subsystem=logging/console-handler:write-attribute(name=level, value=DEBUG)
```

Comment: Nice tip . Except that I'd like to put DEBUG messages in a file , while keeping INFO level messages on the console

Comment: Then just skip the second command. The default file handler is setup to log all levels.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround  (DEBUG msgs include INFO msgs) 
Intercept all DEBUG  msgs in the root logger 
Put a handler that redirects them to a file
 
Put a handler that redirects them to the console
In the definition of the second handler , specify the level INFO

```
<root-logger>
  <level name="DEBUG"/>
  <handlers> 
         <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
         <handler name="FILE"/>
  </handlers>
<root-logger>

<console-handler name="CONSOLE">
  <level name="INFO"/>
    <formatter>
      <named-formatter name="SIMPLE-PATTERN"/>
    </formatter>
</console-handler>
```